# Python object validation thanks to a Schema

Tags: python, schema

I want to validate a python object thanks to a schema. For this I found the [`schema` framework](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/schema).

I would like to validate a numeric string:

```
a = {
    'phone_number': '12233'
}
```

Do you know how can I validate this string thanks to a regex?

At this time, I only know how to perform a string validation:

```
Schema(str).validate('12')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Schema` will call any callables; simply provide a function that uses a regular expression:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile('^12\d+$')

Schema(And(str, lambda x: pattern.match(x) is not None))
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> from schema import Schema, And
>>> pattern = re.compile('^12\d+$')
>>> s = Schema(And(str, lambda x: pattern.match(x) is not None))
>>> s.validate('123234')
'123234'
>>> s.validate('42')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/schema.py", line 153, in validate
    raise SchemaError([None] + x.autos, [e] + x.errors)
schema.SchemaError: <lambda>('42') should evaluate to True
```